# why is my VLC plugin crashing so much

Tags: debugging, plugins, lua, vlc

So i decided to write a VLC plugin in Lua... and I'm totally new to both technology, and I got a plugin to work, but it crashes like every 25 or 30 times I use it. The goal of it is to get the play head to the last 5,7,or 10 seconds of the track.

here is the source:

```
function activate() 
    initialize()
    index=0 -- when activate already playing.

    local d = vlc.dialog("Begin-End" )
    d:add_button("begin",do_begin,1,1,1,1)
    d:add_button("end 10",do_end,3,1,1,1)
    d:add_button("end 7",do_end_7,4,1,1,1)
    d:add_button("end 5", do_end_5,4,2,1,1)

    d:add_button("prev playlist",do_prevplaylist,1,2,1,1)
    d:add_button("next playlist",do_nextplaylist,3,2,1,1)
    d:show()
    update()
end

function initialize()
    input=vlc.object.input()
    d=vlc.input.item():duration()
    index=0
end

function input_changed()
    initialize()
    update()
end
function meta_changed()
end

function deactivate()

end

function close()
    vlc.deactivate()
end

function update()
    if index==1 then
        vlc.var.set(input,"time",0)
    end
    if index==2 then
        vlc.var.set(input,"time",d-10)
    end
    if index==3 then
        vlc.var.set(input, "time", d-7) 
    end
    if index==4 then
        vlc.var.set(input, "time", d-5)
    end
end
function do_nextplaylist()
    vlc.playlist.next()
end
function do_prevplaylist()
    vlc.playlist.prev()
end
function do_begin()
    index = 1
    update()
end
function do_end()
    index = 2
    update()
end
function do_end_7() 
    index = 3
    update()
end
function do_end_5()
    index = 4
    update()
end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What crashes? VCL, or your plugin? Do you get any meaningful feedback? Log file? Windows even log message?   I don't know VCL's plugin system, but I don't see anything wrong with your Lua code. Intermittent crashes can mean a lot of things. You could be hitting some code branch occasionally that's not normally hit (doesn't look like that in your code), you or VCL be failing to release some resource (check VCL's memory usage as you approach the crash), etc.

Comment: thank you for your response... it dose two things... one it will just crash the plugin (that is more the case) and every once and a while it will crash VLC... and I have not looked at the logs... where do I look for that?

Comment: I'm not sure, the interface of VLC is well done. I remember, running even the supplied examples crashes VLC. So, perhaps, you might start by trying minimal examples or the ones provided in the installation, and see if they crash too.